# Asynchronously fill a Strongly Typed Dataset

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, data-binding, asynchronous

I believe everyone is familiar with the traditional way of filling data into a data bound control using visual studio. The VS creates a strongly typed DataSet and call the Fill function of the DataAdapter on form load event just like the code given below:

```
this.applications_infoTableAdapter.Fill(this.bITSS_UIT_dBDataSet_tmpApplication.Applications_info, textBox1.Text);
```

Everything works perfect, except when there is loads of data to be fetched from the database.

When we have more than 500K tuples in the db, and searching needs to be done at server side, even sql server takes some time to return the data. For that duration of time, the UI of the windows forms becomes unresponsive.

For large amounts of data the UI remains unresponsive for a considerable amount of time which is not acceptable.

So, My question is, Is there any asynchronous way of filling the data so the UI remains responsive and we might show a loading animation or anything else we desire, to the user.

I hope I've made myself clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no asynchronous filling in the typed dataset. The query runs on the database, not in your code. The database engine may do the query using multiple cores but the fill call would only get returned when the query is complete and the result get sent back over the wire - synchronously. You can turn off the bookkeeping in your data table via BeginLoadData, but that does not change the way the database server process your query.

If your server is SQL Server, you can use SqlClient async with a SqlConnection that has async=true enabled, however typed dataset does not generate code that uses the SQL Server provider, you need to somehow patch the designer-generated code to use the sql server objects instead of generic ones.

An easier way is to move the creating of the table adapter and filling to a background thread via System.Threading, Background Worker or PPL, so it hangs another thread. If you want pause or resume the data filling, you need to rewrite the query to support paging.

Comment: Thats it? Does C# 4 or 5 have nothing to offer for this?

Comment: You misunderstood what a language can do. A language is a coding convention and has no action code to speak of. It cannot be used to change the behavior of code written by someone else. You can move YOUR code that creates an table adapter and queries the database to a background thread via System.Threading, WinForms BackgroundWorker or PPL. but this has nothing to do with what C# offers.

Comment: Thankyou for your detailed response. I understand that a language cannot speak of itself unless we code. What I was asking is that, is there any way to fetch data from db while keeping the UI thread responsive. I am aware that we can use MultiThreading or BackgroundWorker to achieve the same task, but I wanted to know is there any workaround to fill a strongly typed DS while keeping UI responsive?

Comment: The db engine hangs a thread. To keep UI responsive, hang a background thread.